# Haskell : How to build the Heterogeneous Type Any

Tags: haskell, types

I'd like to build a type to match up to anything but never be used.

Example:

```
type Any = forall a. a
f :: (x, Any) -> (Any, y) -> (x,y)
f (x,_) (_,y) = (x,y)
```

This compiles just fine with `{-# LANGUAGE ImpredicativeTypes #-}` but if I try

```
f ("hi", 2) (3, (1, 2))
```

I get the error:

```
<interactive>:19:9:
    No instance for (Num a) arising from the literal `2'
    Possible fix:
      add (Num a) to the context of a type expected by the context: a
    In the expression: 2
    In the first argument of `f', namely `("hi", 2)'
    In the expression: f ("hi", 2) (3, (1, 2))

<interactive>:19:13:
    No instance for (Num a) arising from the literal `3'
    Possible fix:
      add (Num a) to the context of a type expected by the context: a
    In the expression: 3
    In the second argument of `f', namely `(3, (1, 2))'
    In the expression: f ("hi", 2) (3, (1, 2))
```

Which would be fine if I just wanted x and y to be Num, but what I plan to do with this needs to be much more flexible then that.  I understand that `forall a. a` matches to all types but can only pass a thunk that can never be computed and bottom.  But, I have no desire to ever look into the Any type.

Comment: Why can't you just use another type variable like `z` instead of `Any`?

Comment: because the function I plan to use Any in looks like this [(Any,x)] -> [(y, Any)] -> [(x,y)] on input of [("a",2),(3,4)]

Comment: This is going to very brittle, I'm not sure why you want an existential Any type if you could never use it for anything specific. ``Data.Dynamic`` is the preferred way to handle types that are not known until runtime.

Comment: @AndrewC that will not help

Comment: @AndrewC tested it and it did not work (at least not with GHC 7.8.3)

Comment: @BT That would work with a type signature of `[(a,x)] -> [(y, b)] -> [(x,y)]`.

Comment: You can't pass `2` since it is of type `forall a. Num a => a` which is not type `Any`. The only thing you can pass is `undefined` and similar bottoms.

Comment: Tried Dynamic library and it kind of works, but I can't change all of the arguments first.  So, no not really.

Comment: @chi - Well that bites.  It may be reasonable, but still darn.

Comment: I think you need to add these details about how you plan to use your type back in your question, and perhaps also indicate how you will produce that data which will be filtered by your function.

Comment: My intuition is that you could do it simply with already existing standard functions by rethinking your whole algorithm.

Comment: @chaosmasttter Ah I see now - bottom is the only element of the type `forall a . a`.

Comment: @BT. Why do you actually want this? If you give more context to your problem, you'll perhaps get some good advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there's a fundamental misunderstanding about the `Any` type. Let me explain through a few examples.

An "Any-producer" function

```
f :: ... -> Any
```

can be used to produce a value which is of any type: it returns a string which is also an integer and a pair and an elephant at the same time. Concretely, it returns bottom (or it does not return at all, if you prefer).

An "Any-consumer" function

```
f :: Any -> ...
```

*expects* to be fed with a value of any type: the *caller* has to provide a string which is also an integer and a pair and an elephant at the same time. Concretely, the caller has to pass bottom.

You are trying to pass `2`, which is *not* of any type -- it only is of any *numeric* type. Hence the type error.

If you wanted to write a function that accepts anything, you should write

```
type Any = exists a. a  -- INVALID Haskell
f :: Any -> ...
```

but alas, Haskell does not allow this kind of existential types. If you want that type you have to box it:

```
data Any = forall a . Any a
f :: Any -> ...

caller = f (Any 'd')
```

Alternatively, you can hoist the `exists` to the top-level. Since it is in negative position, it becomes a `forall`

```
f :: (exists a. a) -> ...
-- becomes
f :: forall a. (a -> ...)
```

Comment: Ugh, I forgot about the producer.  That would completely destroy the type safety.  Sad.

Answer (score 5):

It seems from the comments the real question is: how do I type a list written with the literal syntax `["a", False]`?

The answer (fortunately!) is "you can't".

You *can* make an existential type, and wrap each element with the existential. If you want to do this, you can do that this way:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
data Box where
    Box :: a -> Box
```

Then the list `[Box "a", Box False]` will be well typed at type `[Box]`. However, if you're willing to apply a function to each element, then you might as well skip all the type shenanigans and do something like this instead:

```
toss :: a -> ()
toss _ = ()
```

Then `[toss "a", toss False]` has the very understandable type `[()]`.

Answer (score 3):

It can not work, because your `Any` is in fact `All`. It can only be constructed from a expression which has every type (something like `undefined`).

You will need to use `{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-} to build a real`Any`:

```
data Any = forall a . Any a
```

This needs to be a data type, so you will have to create values by using the `Any` constructor but now you can do something like this:

```
f :: [(x, Any)] -> [(Any, y)] -> [(x,y)]
f ((x, _) : xs) ((_, y) : ys) = (x,y) : f xs ys
f _ _ = []

> f [("hi", Any 'a'),("you", Any 3)] [(Any "a", 2),(Any Nothing, 4)]
[("hi",2),("you",4)]
```

Comment: Kind of complicates everything that I was trying to do this with.  But, thank you for your answer.  It's rather cool.